# Modify a single RegEx to also match a middle term from a string

Tags: php, mysql, regex

This *RegEx* : `{=tokenstring[^{}]*(?:{[^{}]*}[^{}]*)*}/g` matches this *string* properly:

```
{=tokenstring?param1=11&param2={token-identifier}&param3={token-child-identifier}&param4=20}
```

(That *string* is a token which is being used in my website. It's value changes dynamically based on the provided request data in the content pages.)

I would like to add one more condition to the *RegEx*.  For example "**param3**", to find if it exists or not in the *string*.

I know this new *RegEx*: `/param3=([^&])/` will get the word "**param3**" from the *string* but how to fit that new *RegEx* into the original *RegEx*?

Comment: You might be able to do this with regex, but if you could split the string first by `&`, and then by `=`, you could greatly simplify the problem.  What tool/ language are you currently using?

Comment: do you mean you want the value of `param3` or you want to make sure param3 exists, if not don't match?

Comment: 1. I am using this Regex tool : http://regexr.com/
2. Want to check param3 exists or not in the above reference string.
3. TIm: splitting the string may not work here as I need to use this RegEx for Database query.

Comment: @AnkitShah, please specify the make/model/brand of your database query language.

Comment: It's PHP & MySql. But you can consider this problem as generic because solution of this can be used either PHP or in MySql end.

Comment: @AnkitShah looks like you have a URL parameter string here. You can use any url library to parse it and split it to parameters and values, it'd be better than implementing everything yourself, especially all in one regex

Comment: @buld0zzr: No, it's not URL. It's a token which is being used in my website. It's value changes dynamically based on the provided request data in the content pages.

Comment: @AnkitShah - No, the solution must be implemented in PHP, not MySQL.  You need too many features of regexp that are not available in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tentative experiment with an online debugger.  Before:

```
{=tokenstring[^{}]*(?:{[^{}]*}[^{}]*)*}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo "before"](https://www.debuggex.com/r/tfc5chnB8q-LIj-X)

After:

```
{=tokenstring[^{}]*(?:{[^{}]*}[^{}]*)*param3=(?:{[^{}]*}[^{}]*)*}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo "after"](https://www.debuggex.com/r/W5mVijJYUSWqGeHL)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a fixed number of parameters, it means you can't write a single regex, since you can't create regular expression with dynamic number of groups. However, you can iterate over matches. For example in PHP it would look like this

```
#Check if token is right
if (preg_match('/\A\{=tokenstring\?param.+\}\Z/s', $subject)) {
    # Successful match. Now iterate over tokens and their params
    preg_match_all('/(param\d+)=(.+?)(?:&|(?:\}$))/s', $subject, $result, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    for ($matchi = 0; $matchi < count($result); $matchi++) {
        $param = $result[$matchi][0];
        $param_value = $result[$matchi][1];
    }
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

UPDATE: The best I could do with a single regex is the case when one parameter could be missing (that is, there're 3 or 4 parameters)

```
{=tokenstring\?(?:(param\d+)=(.+?)(?:&|(?:}$)))(?:(param\d+)=(.+?)(?:&|(?:}$)))(?:(param\d+)=(.+?)(?:&|(?:}$)))|(?:(param\d+)=(.+?)(?:&|(?:}$)))
```

You'll get matched parameters into match groups so you could detect which parameters are missing. Also the order of parameters doesn't matter.

There's also an if-then-else `(?(?=condition)then|else)` construct in regex, but if you can have from 1 to 4 parameters, it means you'll have to write a nested regex of three levels, the top one checking for existence of 4 parameters, another one inside the existence of 3 parameters etc, each repeating itself with an insane number of capturing groups.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I am looking for single RegEx solution in this case. This is because I can't use this solution at MySql level. If I have single RegEX solution then that will work in both PHP & MySql.

Comment: Sorry but your RegEx not worked for me. It's working with example reference string. 

Also for >>You also need support that $ matches at line breaks, there's no other way to detect if } symbol is the end of the string or part of parameter.<< The current RegEx works well in this situation but param3 exists or not check is not there in it.

Comment: @AnkitShah Yeah, it doesn't really work, got confused with matching groups. Would give it another try for a bit more time, but it doesn't look really promising

Comment: @AnkitShah I'd abandon the idea, since the optimization effect from using a single regex is overcomed by the compexity of the task. You can use stored procedures in MySQL to do the task of parsing the string, I'd be more code, but I'd be more readable